# What is the difference between Oracle JDK 8 and Open JDK 8?

Tags: java, ppa, 16.04, jdk, openjdk

There are two kind of JDK available for Ubuntu(Oracle JDK 8 and Open JDK 8).

Which one is recommended for programmer to install ?

Comment: You can use any, but some software explicitly recommends Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle JDK is a proprietary JAVA software by Oracle.

Open JDK is an open-source JAVA software.

There is no "recommended" JDK. You can use either one.